# nattable combobox filter header with group by

Tags: nattable

I am trying to implement nattable with "ComboBoxFilterRowHeaderComposite".

Filtering is working fine but after filtering rows when I try to do group by, it throws following exception

`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:492)
    at ca.odell.glazedlists.FunctionList.listChanged(FunctionList.java:283)
    at ca.odell.glazedlists.event.ListEventAssembler$ListEventFormat.fire(ListEventAssembler.java:424)
    at ca.odell.glazedlists.event.ListEventAssembler$ListEventFormat.fire(ListEventAssembler.java:421)
    at ca.odell.glazedlists.event.SequenceDependenciesEventPublisher$SubjectAndListener.firePendingEvent(SequenceDependenciesEventPublisher.java:445)
    at ca.odell.glazedlists.event.SequenceDependenciesEventPublisher.fireEvent(SequenceDependenciesEventPublisher.java:344)
    at ca.odell.glazedlists.event.ListEventAssembler.commitEvent(ListEventAssembler.java:317)
    at ca.odell.glazedlists.TransformedList.clear(TransformedList.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.extension.glazedlists.groupBy.GroupByDataLayer$1.run(GroupByDataLayer.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.extension.glazedlists.groupBy.GroupByDataLayer.updateTree(GroupByDataLayer.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.extension.glazedlists.groupBy.GroupByDataLayer.update(GroupByDataLayer.java:313)
    at java.util.Observable.notifyObservers(Observable.java:159)
    at java.util.Observable.notifyObservers(Observable.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.extension.glazedlists.groupBy.GroupByModel.update(GroupByModel.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.extension.glazedlists.groupBy.GroupByModel.addGroupByColumnIndex(GroupByModel.java:44)`

---

Here is my structure for ComboBoxFilterRowHeaderComposite:

`filterRowHeaderLayer = new ComboBoxFilterRowHeaderComposite<T>(
            bodyLayerStack.getFilterList(), 
bodyLayerStack.getGlazedListsEventLayer(), bodyLayerStack.getSortedList(),
                columnAccessor, columnHeaderLayer, dataProvider, configRegistry);`

where,

columnAccessor = new ReflectiveColumnPropertyAccessor(propertyNames);

columnGroupHeaderLayer = new DynamicColumnGroupHeaderLayer(sortHeaderLayerStack, bodyLayerStack.getSelectionLayer(),
                bodyLayerStack.getColumnGroupModel(), tr);

DataProvider is com.vanguard.tip.epm.platform.ui.grid.next.DynamicColumnHeaderDataProvider;

After that

`CornerLayerStack cornerLayerStack = new CornerLayerStack(rowHeaderLayerStack, filterRowHeaderLayer);`

`CompositeLayer gridLayer = new GridLayer(bodyLayerStack, filterRowHeaderLayer, rowHeaderLayerStack, cornerLayerStack);`

Then Add gridLayer in GroupByHeaderLayer:

`groupByHeaderLayer = new GroupByHeaderLayer(bodyLayerStack.getGroupByModel(), gridLayer, columnHeaderLayerStack.getDataProvider(),
new GroupByHeaderConfigurationWrapper(bodyLayerStack.getGroupByModel(), columnHeaderLayerStack.getDataProvider(), bodyLayerStack.getColumnGroupModel()));`

`CompositeLayer groupByComposite = new CompositeLayer(1, 2);`

`groupByComposite.setChildLayer(GroupByHeaderLayer.GROUP_BY_REGION, groupByHeaderLayer, 0, 0);`

`groupByComposite.setChildLayer("Grid", gridLayer, 0, 1);`

I hope this will give you some clarity about my use of Nattable.

When I use text base filter with same structure Grouping is working fine:

`filterStrategy = new DefaultGlazedListsFilterStrategy<T>(bodyLayerStack.getFilterList(), columnAccessor, configRegistry);`

`this.filterRowHeaderLayer = new FilterRowHeaderComposite<T>(filterStrategy, columnHeaderLayer, dataProvider, configRegistry);`

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Quick help without further information is not possible. It is not clear what you are doing and how.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug for that combination. I created the following ticket for this:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=508334

Comment: Thanks Dirk to open ticket for this. If possible let me know when can we fix this because we want to use combobox filter soon. If there is any other way to achieve this please provide me detail.

Comment: Should be fixed with the latest 1.5 SNAPSHOT build #578

Comment: great!! Thank you Dirk.

Comment: Hi Dirk, can you please provide me release date of Nattable 1.5?

Comment: No, I don't have concrete plans yet

Comment: oh!.. can you please advice what is the best way to get this fix in 1.4 release?

Comment: there is no way to do this, despite using the fixed classes in your local space and trying to use those classes instead of the NatTable ones.

Comment: Ok.. do you know any known risk to go in prod with nattable 1.5 snapshot - build 583?

Comment: The same as you would have with a locally fixed 1.4. There are currently known issues related to a new printing feature and a performance issue for tables with big column counts. If you don't have columns with thousands of columns and don't use the new advanced printing features there should be no risk.