# Exception in Nattable Combo filter

Tags: nattable

while using combobox filter in nattable, I am getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "pool-20-thread-6" java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at ca.odell.glazedlists.impl.adt.barcode2.SimpleTreeIterator.value(SimpleTreeIterator.java:308)
    at ca.odell.glazedlists.SortedList$SortedListIterator.next(SortedList.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.filterrow.combobox.FilterRowComboBoxDataProvider.collectValues(FilterRowComboBoxDataProvider.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.extension.glazedlists.filterrow.GlazedListsFilterRowComboBoxDataProvider.handleLayerEvent(GlazedListsFilterRowComboBoxDataProvider.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.layer.AbstractLayer.fireLayerEvent(AbstractLayer.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.layer.AbstractLayer.handleLayerEvent(AbstractLayer.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.layer.AbstractLayer.fireLayerEvent(AbstractLayer.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.util.CalculatedValueCache$1.run(CalculatedValueCache.java:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please check below URL to see how I am using combobox filter.
[nattable combobox filter header with group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40826504/nattable-combobox-filter-header-with-group-by)

Answer (score 0):

Try the latest SNAPSHOT build. We recently fixed another concurrency issue.

Please also note that Stackoverflow is not the support forum for NatTable! If you have issues like the above open a ticket via [Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=NatTable) or ask on the [NatTable forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=240).